# Creating custom CRS for India toposheets using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, india

Indian toposheets (pre-2000 series) of 1:50k scale are in Polyconic projection, with Everest 1956 spheroid and India-nepal datum. How do I create a custom CRS in QGIS to represent this, so that I can then reproject the topo corners (tic points) to UTM-WGS 84 and then geo-reference the toposheet.

Comment: Found the answer: search for 37203 in the filter when specifying the output CRS in the Georeference add-on. EPSG=37203 is nothing but Everest 1956 with India-Nepal datum.

Comment: technically 37203 is ESRI, not EPSG.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually using 37203 does not solve the problem. Although choosing this in ERDAS might work, the proj.4 definition of 37203 is incomplete, because it does not contain the delta-x, delta-y, delta-z shift information. So one still ends up with a 200-300m error if one uses 37203. Defining a custom CRS as: +proj=longlat +a=6377301.243 +b=6356100.2284  +towgs84=295.00,736.00,257.00,0,0,0,0 +no_defs  solves the problem.

Comment: @Sharad.
***`UPDATE: Actually using 37203 does not solve the problem. Although choosing this in ERDAS might work, the proj.4 definition of 37203 is incomplete, because it does not contain the delta-x, delta-y, delta-z shift information. So one still ends up with a 200-300m error if one uses 37203. Defining a custom CRS as: +proj=longlat +a=6377301.243 +b=6356100.2284 +towgs84=295.00,736.00,257.00,0,0,0,0 +no_defs solves the problem. – Sharad Jun 9 '14 at 7:55`*** Thank you very much, New Custom CRS solved the problem by 95%. Further more Geo referencing is needed to achieve more accuracy. Than

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96405)

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126546/transformation-parameters-for-everest-datum-to-wgs84. Related ticket: https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io/issues/49